# Import JScience Measure into NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I have a basic question.  I am trying to use the measurement functionality in JScience.  I downloaded the .jar files (http://java.net/projects/jscience/downloads) I created a new library with all of the .jar files loaded.

My "tree" is:
[image]

My import statement is:

```
import javax.measure;
```

The compiler complains that package javax.measure does not exist.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for importing in Java is:

**For an individual class:**

```
import com.mypackage.ClassName;
```

**For an entire package:**

```
import com.mypackage.*;
```

To import the entire `measure` package, you can use:

```
import javax.measure.*;
```

- [Using Package Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)